# Error not being thrown inside async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have an async function which inserts some data into a database (using [mariadb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariadb)). This insert may fail due to a duplicate unique key, so it'll throw an error (and it actually does), but when I try to throw it again to catch it through the Promise, it doesn't work; it always seems to end in a successful case, even if it has thrown the error.

I tried changing the then/catch order, and I used `reject(err);` instead of `throw err;` but none of that works.

Here's the POST declaration:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body || {};
    createUser(user).then(() => {
        res.status(201); 
        res.send('Created!'); // This is ALWAYS sent, with the error thrown or not
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('thrown'); // This is never printed
        res.status(500);
        res.send('Failed');
    });
});
```

And this is the create user function:

```
async function createUser(user) {
    let conn;
    try {
        conn = await db.getConnection();
        const res = await conn.query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)', [user.name, user.password]); // Shorter example
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('catched'); // This is printed
        throw err; // This is run but nothing thrown
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            return conn.end(); // This is run after catching
        }
    }
}
```

The idea would be to get that exception caught by the Promise so I can send an error message instead of a success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your return statement inside your `finally`. In an `async` function after throwing an exception if you catch it throw `finally` and return something, instead of throwing it resolves the promise into your returned value. From what I see you do not need the ended connection's object as the return value which means all you have to do is to change your function to this:

```
async function createUser(user) {
    let conn;
    try {
        conn = await db.getConnection();
        const res = await conn.query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)', [user.name, user.password]); // Shorter example
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('catched'); // This is printed
        throw err; // This is run but nothing thrown
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            conn.end(); // This is run after catching
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize the return statement was even there, it might be a copy-pasting error.
As you said, the promise would resolve before catching if something was returned first.